# How to bind field in django model and celery worker result

Tags: python, django, celery

The question is theoretical and I just want to understand in which direction to move. I have the model below. The user fills in the form (word, translation) and at the moment the form is saved, celery worker is launched to create an mp3 file of the "word" field. How to link created mp3 file and Word model? How to organize the storage of these files? Thank you very much for your attention.

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    translate = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    audio = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

   
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #start the celery worker to generate mp3
        self.word = self.word.lower()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to link created mp3 file and Word model? How to organize the storage of these files?